# How to concate joined table fields for xml

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, postgresql, postgresql-9.2

Hi have data structure like this :

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE test_names (
  id serial primary key,
  name character varying(50),
  age int
);

INSERT INTO test_names(name,age) values ('name1',10),('name2',20);

CREATE TEMP TABLE test_names_details (
  id serial primary key,
  test_names_id int,
  col1 int,
  col2 int,
  col3 int
);

INSERT INTO test_names_details(test_names_id,col1,col2,col3)
VALUES(1,2,3,4),(1,5,6,7),(1,8,9,10),(2,20,21,22),(2,23,24,25)
```

Want from this tables select data like xml :

```
<info>
  <maininfo>
    <pn name="name">name1</pn>
    <age name="age">10</age>
  </maininfo>
  <data>
    <row>
      <col1 name="col1">2</col1>
      <col2 name="col2">3</col1>
      <col3 name="col3">4</col1>
    </row>
    <row>
      <col1 name="col1">5</col1>
      <col2 name="col2">6</col1>
      <col3 name="col3">7</col1>
    </row>
    <row>
      <col1 name="col1">8</col1>
      <col2 name="col2">9</col1>
      <col3 name="col3">10</col1>
    </row>
  </data>

  <maininfo>
    <pn name="name">name2</pn>
    <age name="age">20</age>
  </maininfo>
  <data>
    <row>
      <col1 name="col1">20</col1>
      <col2 name="col2">21</col1>
      <col3 name="col3">22</col1>
    </row>
    <row>
      <col1 name="col1">23</col1>
      <col2 name="col2">24</col1>
      <col3 name="col3">25</col1>
    </row>
  </data>

</info>
```

How to do it ?

Comment: @RobertGoldman I have no idea how to do it

Comment: And is there any reason why you wish to return the XML straight from the database? Why not build the XML on application level?

Comment: @RobertGoldman We have business logic in database that why we need it. I have no idea how select data where after name comes details then new name with details and so on. If select will correct i will concate strings  . Any idea how to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap this in a function and off you go! ;-)

```
SELECT
'<info>' || 
    string_agg(
    '<maininfo>' ||
        '<pn name="name">' || name || '</pn>' ||
        '<age name="age">' || age || '</age>' ||
    '</maininfo>' ||
    '<data>' ||
        (SELECT
            string_agg(
        '<row>' ||
            '<col name="col1">'||col1||'</col>' ||
            '<col name="col2">'||col2||'</col>' ||
            '<col name="col3">'||col3||'</col>' ||
        '</row>', '')
        FROM test_names_details WHERE test_names_id = test_names.id
        ) ||
    '</data>'
    , '') ||
'</info>'
FROM test_names
```

Comment: Thank you very much